# Server Sent Events are not "text/event-stream"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-sent-events

I want to add Server Sent Events (SSE) into my project that runs on nodeJS (Express). As a start  I have used this code: https://github.com/hnasr/javascript_playground/blob/master/server-sent-events/index.js. This example code works like a charm when running it in isolation but when I'm incorporating the code into my (bigger) project I got some errors that I'm unable to solve. I hope you can help me. I think messed up the code in the routes folder, not sure tho.

I use NodeJs with express as my server.
The folder `app.js` contains this code.

```
    #Routing code
    var router_price_24h_changes  = require('./routes/24hours');
    app.use('/24hours', router_price_24h_changes);
    
    #>>>a lot of other (probably unnecessary code)<<<

    #Added this 
    app.get("/24hours-events", (req,res) => {
    
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
      send(res);
      console.log("Stream")
    
    })
    
    let i = 0;
    function send (res) {
      console.log("send")
      res.write("data: " + `hello!${i++}\n\n`);
    
      setTimeout(() => send(res), 1000);
    }
```

This is what my `routes-24hours.js` looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  
  const myHtml = fs.readFileSync('./24hours.html', 'utf-8');
  const changes = fs.readFileSync("./changes.json", 'utf-8');
  const changes2 = fs.readFileSync("./changes2", 'utf-8');

  res.send(myHtml.replace(/data/g, JSON.stringify(({changes ,changes2 }), null, 0)));

});

module.exports = router;
```

When visiting the `24hours-events` webpage from my chrome browser I typed this

```
let sse = new EventSource("http://localhost:3000/24hours-events");
```

In the console log, this was the response:

```
http://localhost:3000/24hours-events 404 (Not Found)
```

Note: I have not created a "24hours-events" html file

In the isolated SSE test version I added `sse.onmessage = console.log` after it and it logged the server events.

If something is not clear and more information is needed to answer this question, I would be more then happy to hear from you.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/event-stream" charset="utf-8" />` makes no sense, so as a first step, remove that (it’s HTML claiming to be something other than HTML).

Comment: @Ry- Thanks for your feedback, I have removed the metadata. You you know the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```js
> app.get("http://localhost:3000/24hours", (req,res) => {
> ```

When defining a route, you should only specify the path, not the full URL:

```js
app.get("/24hours", (req, res) => {
```

The HTML being received might be a 404 page. (You should look in your network panel, or open http://localhost:3000/24hours directly, to confirm that.)

> In the metadata of the 24hours.html file I have added this:
>
> ```html
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/event-stream" charset="utf-8" />
> ```

Remove that, it’s incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have delete the metadata and changed to full url to the path. I still got the same error.

Comment: @AttackTheWar: Do you see your “send” and “Stream” `console.log`s? When you open the page on its own, what does it look like?

Comment: @AttackTheWar: It looks like you’re trying to use `/24hours` for both the event stream and the page that requests the event stream. That’s not convenient. Can you change the URL of one of them? Like `/24hours` for the page and `/24hours-events` for the stream?

Comment: I do not see any logs when opening the page. I have separated the page (/24hours) and the event stream (/24hours-events). Now when I call "let sse = new EventSource("http://localhost:3000/24hours-events");" in the browser. It give me: 404 Not Found, error.  I have updated my question.

Comment: @AttackTheWar: Where is `app.get("/24hours-events", (req,res) => {` defined? Try putting it right under the `app.use('/24hours', …)`.